# How can I implement authentication in Django

Tags: django

I am new to Django.
I am going to build simple register and login fullstack application by using React and Django.
My problem is when I received register request with form data.
Is it ok to create custom table for users?
I am going to create another table related to user table.
So in that case, there must be id in the users.
That's why I am going to create custom table.
Please help me it is good practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can abstract from `AbstractBaseUser` and then you can customise the user model and to specify it in your settings file.

Please see the django documentation here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model

Answer (score -1):

In Django you can link between multiple table by different relationships depends on what you want like:

```
OneToOne
ForeignKey
ManyToMany
```

And by default when you create a model django create a **pk field** it is ID for table, you can make another field as a primary key for model

When you use one of those relationships django by default use **model id** to link between them

and you can also create a custom user model to use it

Good luck